# Cannot find Transformer function in module in caffe

Tags: python, caffe

Here is the error i get  when i run the transformer function for preprocessing the image.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tst.py", line 18, in

transformer = caffe.io.Transformer({'data': net.blobs['data'].data.shape})
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Transformer'

Comment: In which directory are you running your program? You might want to see [this](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/782).

Comment: what version of caffe are you running? what branch? Transformer was introduced later than other caffe.io functions.

Comment: @Shai I am using the modified caffe required for deconvnet from https://github.com/HyeonwooNoh/caffe     will i have to update my caffe.io file?

Comment: @VirataGarwal you need to examine the io.py file if your branch.

Comment: @Shai can u suggest any changes needed to be made in the io.py file?

Comment: @GoodDeeds I am running my program in the directory as shown  **/home/virat/deep/tst.py** and my caffe directory is **/home/virat/deep/newcaffe/caffe..**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually figured it out.

The io.py file did not contain the class Trasnformer. Maybe it was missing in the modified caffe. I took the class from the original BVLC caffe and pasted it in the io.py file.
Link to io.py of BVLC caffe
https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/python/caffe/io.py

works for me.